# Heatsink Mount (standoff) screw broke off in motherboard backplate

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cooling, screws

### Partial Solution (EDIT)

I returned the board and the heat sink to Amazon. They are going to have a new board to me in 4 days. Honestly, to anyone reading this, I would try to do a return through your merchant (especially if its amazon). If that fails, try to do an RMA. I am leaving the answer section alone since this will not be the solution people will be looking for when it comes to this issue. If someone knows how to properly drill the screw out or remove the backplate please answer the question for future users who cannot do a return or an RMA.

### Situation

I was mounting my heatsink to my new motherboard and one of the four mounting stand-off screws--about halfway through tightening--broke off. The head came off and the threaded portion is still inside the motherboards backplate. I believe the screw was defective from the factory.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to remove this threaded portion? I am returning the heatsink to Amazon to get a new one. So, I will have new screws, etc. But I will need to do 1 of 2 things (that I know of -- please correct me if I am wrong) in order to attach the new heatsink.

### Possible Solutions I thought of

Solution 1) I will need to remove the threaded portion of whats left of the screw from the motherboard stock backplate. (I would like to do this if possible)

or

Solution 2) I will need to remove the stock backplate from the motherboard and use the backplate that came with the heatsink (Note: both backplates are fine to use, and not using the backplate supplied did not contribute to the issue).

### What I know about these solutions

Solution 1) I have read that you can drill out the screws threaded portion with tiny drill bit. I do not know how dependable this is, and I do not want to damage the internal threading on the motherboards backplate.

Solution 2) I have no idea how much stress this could put on the motherboard or if it is even removable...

### Hardware

Here is the hardware involved:

Motherboard: MSI x99S SLI Plus

Heatsink: Coolermaster Hyper 212 Evo

CPU: 2011v3 Intel i7 5820k (The Evo comes with 2 sets of mounting standoffs. One standard, and one specifically for 2011 socket. I am using the 2011 socket mounting screws since my CPU is a 2011)

---

Any help would be appreciated. I really would like to avoid frying my board. All of the components are functioning, even the CPU with 3/4 heatsink screws tightened down. I installed Windows and everything and never saw temps above 41C. But I want this to be done right especially when I go into overclocking territory.

### Picture

---

Here is a picture from a random forum online I found. It shows the same symptoms my board is having even though his issue is slightly different (his was a pressure screw that broke, mine was a standoff screw that broke) His "problem area" is on the bottom left.

It will give you a very good idea of what my issue looks like physically:
[image: Shows the symptoms]

### Additional Details

---

It is actually a screw that goes through the MOBO into its backplate. So the case is not involved here.

Comment: Are you talking about a grounding (mount) stand-off screw? Or the heatsink bolts?

Comment: Stand-off screw. Its also for the intel 2011 CPU line. So that is a key detail. I will edit my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am at work, so I cannot get a picture of my exact PC. But I know of a picture online that shows the same symptoms for a slightly different issue. That would probably help a lot.

Comment: Alright, Added a picture of someone else's motherboard with the same symptoms.

Comment: So a screw that goes through the motherboard and into the case? The head broke off?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19202/discussion-between-dean-knight-and-raystafarian).

Comment: You might be able to use a [screw extractor](http://homerepair.about.com/od/interiorhomerepair/ss/screw_extractor.htm). I don't know if they make them small enough for PC screws :/

Comment: My suggestion take it to a electronics repair shop.  Explain the situation and see if they have any ideas.  But you will have to accept there is significant risk in any solution you attempt.  There are likely runs on reverse side of the board and internal to the board that could be damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar thing happen to me using the same heatsink, a Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO, with an x79 motherboard.

Just to clarify, I was installing the heatsink's standoffs onto the motherboard.  I was able to get three installed, but the fourth one broke off.  Here it is in the lower right:

[image: Hyper 212 EVO Standoff Broken On Motherboard]

Here is the thick part of the broken standoff:

[image: Thick Part of Standoff]

I had a couple of thoughts for removing the broken standoff:

1. Use a cutting tool (dremel like) to create a channel in the broken standoff, suitable for removing the standoff with a flat blade screwdriver.
2. Use a drill bit designed for removing screws with a stripped or broken head.

I opted for the second option as I was afraid of using a dremel to cut into the motherboard.

I put the drill bit into my drill and carefully placed the bit on top of the broken standoff.  The drill bit is "left handed" meaning that it drills in the counter-clockwise direction.

I turned the drill bit slightly and the standoff started to come out.  A bit more turning, and the standoff completely came out.

Here is a picture of the drill bit and standoff (out of the motherboard):

[image: left-handed drill bit and standoff removed]

Finally, here is the motherboard without the broken standoff:

[image: motherboard, standoff removed]

Comment: I asked this so long ago I barely remembered asking the question. Definitely deserve a checkmark for this though so congrats on answering a 9 year old question. Did not know they made such small bits for this.